# c++ link error if function is implemented in .cpp

Tags: c++, static, singleton, linker-errors

If  I implement the create method of the class in .cpp I get

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: __thiscall Singleton::Singleton(void)" (??0Singleton@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Singleton::create(void)" (?create@Singleton@@SAXXZ

However if  I implement the method inside the header file it compiles without any error :S

header file

```
 #pragma once
 #include <iostream>
class Singleton
{
 public:

static Singleton * getInstance()
{
    return s_instance;
}

static void create();
static void destroy();

void help();

protected:

static Singleton * s_instance;
Singleton();
};
```

source file:

```
#include "Singleton.h"

Singleton * Singleton::s_instance = NULL;

 void Singleton::create()
{
    if (!s_instance)
    {
         s_instance = new Singleton;
    }
}



void Singleton::destroy()
{
    delete s_instance;
    s_instance = NULL;
}
```

However If I implement the create method inside the header it does not throws any error

Header file with create method implemented in it

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Singleton
{
public:

    static Singleton * getInstance()
    {
        return s_instance;
    }

    static void create(){
        if (!s_instance)
        {
            s_instance = new Singleton;
        }
    }
    static void destroy();


protected:

    static Singleton * s_instance;
    Singleton();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cpp, your create function is trying to initialize Singleton, by using new operator, but you dont give it an constructor. Try to give an implementation to `Singleton()`. i.e.:

```
protected:

    static Singleton * s_instance;
    Singleton() {}
};
```

Comment: Bah.  You beat me to it.

Comment: there is no good reason why moving the implementation of `getInstance()` should affect the problem of the missing constructor definition. the constructor is *declared* in both cases. but then some other stuff, such as the `help()` function, is also missing, so i suspect the given source is not exactly the real source.

Comment: Note: the easiest and also most meaningful is to instead **remove** the constructor declaration. the constructor doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you ommit Singleton declaration, how do you ensure that no other instantion methods are used, e.g., `new Singleton()`?

Comment: @TomásBadan: why should you? `Singleton` is an empty class (disregarding the singleton pointer member). It's designed for derivation (has `protected` members).

Answer (score 0):

### The problem.

You have *declared* a default constructor, and you're using it (in a `new` expression), but you haven't implemented it.

### Fix.

Simply *remove* the constructor declaration:

```
protected:

    static Singleton * s_instance;
    // Singleton();  -- don't have this. Remove it.
};
```

### Other matters.

With `protected` features the class is designed for inheritance, so how does one ensure that a derived class can only be instantiated via the singleton machinery?

Well you don't have much control over derived classes, so the *easiest* is just to document that each derived class should declare and define a non-`public` default constructor.

However, there is a trick that can be used to enforce this, based on the fact that a **virtual base** must be initialized by the most derived class. This can be used to force client code to add a final class derivation at bottom. Where that most derived class is a template instantiation, which defines a non-public constructor.

A more practical alternative is to turn things upside-down.

That is, instead of designing the `Singleton` class for derivation (signalled by protected stuff), design it to *inherit from* a client code class. Again this means using templates. Andrei Alexandrescu discussed a number of singleton approaches using this idea, in his classic book “Modern C++ Design”.

Comment: I believe the OP is taking this code from this book http://www.amazon.com/For-Game-Programmers-Development-Series/dp/1584504528 and I'm getting same problem. Inside the class, there is `Singleton(); // hidden constructor` Is it a bug in the code? Also, he used `static` in the definition `static void Singleton::Create() {...}` Why he does that?

Comment: @CroCo: It's an attempt at enforcing that no other instances can be created. But it's misguided, it cannot work, because this is designed as a base class (indicated by `protected`), the accessibility is not inherited, and it's the derived class that needs this enforcement. I.e. it's a design level bug. The `static` is OK for `Create` because `Create` only needs access to the `static` member variable.